# The history and origin of the Argument Principle ( or Cauchy's argument principle)

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, complex-analysis

I am looking for a book that discusses The history and origin of the Argument Principle ( or Cauchy's argument principle) Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit to tell us what you have tried so people do not spend time recommending books you have already rejected?

Comment: [Smithies, Cauchy and the Creation of Complex Function Theory, p. 177](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cauchy_and_the_Creation_of_Complex_Funct/RWf3-PwokpMC?hl=en&gbpv=0).